# Dodge Ram SRT-10 Tires

Tags: tires, truck, viper

One of the tire or wheel (I'm not sure which one is doing the squeak ing) on Ram SRT-10 is squeaking.

What may be the problem?

Also my Dad keeps putting on the wheels this spray from autozone.

But it really doesn't help

Comment: When does it make the noise? While going down the road? Slow or fast squeak? Does it stay the same as you increase speed? What kind of squeak is it (describe it better)? You gotta help us here a little bit if you want an intelligent answer.

Comment: It starts to usually squeak when going down road. But really it start to squeak whenever, @Paulster2

Comment: Would you please answer the rest of my questions to the best of your ability? From your comment, you are saying it squeaks when you are sitting still as well? I know this isn't what you mean, so please ....

Comment: When I mean't it squeaks whenever, the truck has to be moving in order for it to squeak. The squeak sounds like a fast squeak, @Paulster2

Comment: Bad bearing?‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: What is a "bearing", @JMusser ?

Comment: I'm on the app. And if I click on link it says "Unfortunately Stack Exchange has stopped" But I searched it up any way. I'm not sure if the wheel bearing is bad, @JMusser

Comment: It's probably the brakes ... but the lack of information has really left me befuddled.

Comment: My Dad said something about that he wanted to change the brakes and tires, @Paulster2